# Python Array Addition recursion

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

So I was doing coderbyte's challenge and I have problems with one:
ArrayAdditionI, here's the statement of the problem:

'''
Using the Python language, have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr 
and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, 
otherwise return the string false. 
For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. 
The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers. 
'''

Since I couldn't do it, I researched for a solution and I found this:

```
def countFor(arr, m, s0):
  if len(arr) == 0:
    return False
  a0 = arr[0]
  ar = arr[1:]

  sw = s0 + a0
  if sw == m:
    return True
  if countFor(ar, m, sw):
    return True
  if countFor(ar, m, s0):
    return True
  return False

def ArrayAdditionI(arr): 

  m = max(arr)
  arr.remove(m)
  return str(countFor(arr, m, 0)).lower()
```

Now, I'm trying to understand what exactly the code does on every loop, I printed out the output for every loop of this list [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]:

```
Input:  [4, 6, 10, 1, 3] 23 0
a0:  4
ar:  [6, 10, 1, 3]
sw:  4
Input:  [6, 10, 1, 3] 23 4
a0:  6
ar:  [10, 1, 3]
sw:  10
Input:  [10, 1, 3] 23 10
a0:  10
ar:  [1, 3]
sw:  20
Input:  [1, 3] 23 20
a0:  1
ar:  [3]
sw:  21
Input:  [3] 23 21
a0:  3
ar:  []
sw:  24
Input:  [] 23 24
Input:  [] 23 21
Input:  [3] 23 20
a0:  3
ar:  []
sw:  23
True
```

and I follow and understand what's going on, until the last three loops, I don't what part of the code makes it go from "Input: [] 23 24" to "Input : [] 23 21" to "Input:  [3] 23 20".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright - here are the calls. Child calls are indented with respect to their parents:

- Call `countFor([4, 6, 10, 1, 3], 23, 0)`

  - Call `countFor([6, 10, 1, 3], 23, 4)` from the first `if`
  - Call `countFor([10, 1, 3], 23, 10)` from the first `if`

    - Call `countFor([1, 3], 23, 20)` from the first `if`
    - Call `countFor([3], 23, 21)` from the first `if`

      - Call `countFor([], 23, 24)` from the first `if`
      - Call `countFor([], 23, 21)` from the second `if`
    - Call `countFor([3], 23, 20)` from the second `if`

Key point is that the second recursive call in `countFor` is not in an `elif` - it is an `if` in its own right, so after we come back up the call-stack, the second recursive call can also happen.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't traced all of the logic, just the input and update at the top of the routine.

At **[] 23 24**, let's follow the logic:

```
if sw == m:
```

Nope ... that's 24 vs 23 ...

```
if countFor(ar, m, sw):
```

This produces your **[] 23 24** line.
Since the array has 0 elements, the call immediately returns **False**.

```
if countFor(ar, m, s0):
```

This produces your **[] 23 21** line.  Again, the empty array gets an immediate **False**.

We fall one more line and return a **False** to the previous call.

---

The call that produced this one was the first **countFor**, calling with

```
if countFor([3], 23, 21):
```

where that 21 is the value of sw.  We drop to the second call, the one with s0.  At this point, s0 is 20, so the call looks like:

```
if countFor([3], 23, 20):
```

... and *this* call sees that 20+3 = 23 = m, so it returns **True**.

Does that clarify things for you?

Answer (score 0):

just use the package `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

def arrayChallenge(numbers):
    expected_sum = max(numbers)
    numbers.remove(expected_sum)
    
    result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1)
          for seq in combinations(numbers, i)
          if sum(seq) == expected_sum]

    return len(result) > 0

print(arrayChallenge([4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]))
```